SQL Server: BULK INSERT fails with 'You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement' on SQL Login but works with Windows Login
I'm trying to enable BULK INSERT for a SQL Server login, but I keep encountering this error:

You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement

Here's what I've done so far:
1. Windows user setup: when I use my Windows account (Windows authentication) to run the BULK INSERT, everything works perfectly, and the data is inserted successfully into the table.
2. SQL Server login setup:
I created a new SQL Server login (SQL Server authentication) named bulkUser.
Under "Login Properties", I assigned the following server roles:

bulkadmin
dbcreator

I then logged in with bulkUser and created a new contained database. After that, I created a new database user in this database and assigned the db_owner role to this new database user.
3. BULK INSERT attempt:
I created a simple table in the newly created database and tried running the BULK INSERT statement using bulkUser, but it fails with the error:

You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement

4. File Permissions:

The .csv file I'm trying to load is on my local machine (under desktop)
I tried granting modify and write permissions on the folder where the .csv file is located to the account under which SQL Server is running (NT Service\LOCALHOST)
Despite this, the error persists.

Additional details:

SQL Server Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2022 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0

The BULK INSERT works perfectly fine when I run it under my Windows user, but I can't get it to work with the SQL Login, even though it has both bulkadmin and db_owner roles

I'm using a local file path for the BULK INSERT


So is it even possible to use bulk on SQL Server instance, or is it only available for Windows user?

I dont get it, a partial database? You mean contained? The user created in such db doesn't have any connection with the login because it's partial, and the user don't have bulkadmin role, so it seems to work as you have set it up (ie. it shouldn't work)

So, are you saying that having BULK INSERT in a contained database is not possible because of that, and that it only works for 'normal' databases?

No. Rather that your user doesnt have bulk rights because it's not connected to login

Hmm so the solution would be to create Login then gave him Server role bulkadmin and under User Mapping choose the contained database and give db_owner under Database role membership for, then Log in with that user and try bulk insert statement?

There are two possible reasons for this behavior.
If you are inserting from file, then you must have access to that file, but: in case of windows authentication - the user is accessing file. in case of server login - the server is accessing file. So you need to check under what credentials SQL Server is running and ensure that this user is able to read the source file.
Another possible reason is much rare and is more like a known bug. If you are on Linux - then bulkadmin is not supported and you must use sysadmin role.
